# Change position of CommandField "Update" and "Cancel" buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, .net-4.0

The `CommandField` of my gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="70px" />
```

Clicking on "Edit" will show the "Update" and "Cancel" buttons like so:

[image]

Is there an *easy* way to change the position of those two buttons so that they look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `TemplateField`, and give the buttons a reserved `CommandName` (Edit, Update, Cancel, Delete) then you can give them any style and position in the GridView you want.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Update</asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```